# How to do typing in django model field?

Tags: python, django, typing

With the recent addition of inlay types for python in VS Code I noticed that the typing for a Field will look like this:
[image]

As you can see it is `Field[Unknown, Unknown]`. And as you know if you don't provide a type to a field, you won't get attribute hints for the field, and the field will be shown as `Unknown`.
You could just provide an `str` type if you for example have a `CharField`, something like this:

`field: str = models.CharField()`

The problem is, if you want to use a strongly typed linter - it will show you an error, that the assigned value is not of type `str`.

So I saw this inlay and I started playing around with this generic, and I noticed that the second parameter of the generic will be the type used to represent the field attribute:
[image]

My question is, does anyone know what is the first parameter of the generic used for, and where is this generic even created, because inside of the package I see that the `Field` class does not inherit any Generics.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `Field` *isn't* generic, so I'm not sure what VS Code is doing.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well, I know that it does not inherit from `Generic`. Maybe there is some other way to create a generic. I don't think that this is a simple bug in VS Code, it does it too good to be a bug.

Comment: I searched the entire source of my version of Django, and the only two classes I can find that are generic are `BaseManager` and `QuerySet`. Are you sure you don't have a [library](https://github.com/sbdchd/django-types/blob/main/README.md) that introduces that functionality?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Just did `pip freeze`, no typing libraries were there. + I don't think a library can change the behavior of another library without importing it (by that I mean that it can not alter the `Field` class when I did `Field[int, str]` - it would cause an error if the Field would not be `Generic`)

Comment: I suppose that VSCode installs stubs internally (like `mypy --install-types` does), because Field in Django itself is not Generic. Have a look at [django-stubs](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs). TL:DR type params are _ST and _GT - setter and getter type, resp. So `Field[X, Y]` is a field with `__set__(self, val: X, /) -> None` and  `__get__(self) -> Y`. Read about Field typing [here](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/master/django-stubs/db/models/fields/__init__.pyi).

Comment: Warning: this stub package is almost useless without plugin, and plugin works only for `mypy`, so you'll have many false positives. Plugin is involved even in Field types resolution (see `_pyi_private_set_type` and co in source code), for example, during lookup on querysets (like `model__related`). But it is really great and powerful, so for doing typed Django you should consider switching to mypy and using this plugin, if this is an option for you.

Comment: (sorry, I didn't have morning coffee before writing this, should be `__get__(self, instance, owner) -> Y` and `__set__(self, instance, value: X) -> None`, ofc)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Django does not allow mutating fields since a change to a field of a model would lead to a database migration.

Nevertheless under the hood many fields use the same types and are basically replaceable. I.e. `ImageField` just stores a path to a string similar to what i `CharField` could do.  Allthough the inner representation of data, or how the data is stored in the field might be different for some fields.

Still all of the fields come with a huge functionality and are usually deeply embedded and wired into the framework. Therefore django model fields are not generic. I guess your IDE is doing something, ... not appropriate :)

In the documentation you can find additional information on fields. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#field-types) you can find a list of all built-in fields.

**edit:**
I was thinking some more about the issue. almost all fields, I *believe* all of them, extend the `models.Field` class. So this might be the reason your IDE is doing this. Some polymorphic thingy has been activated in the code generator or something.

Comment: I already said that but if the IDE was doing that I would not be able to do the typing `Field[int, str]` if the `Field` class was not generic, It would cause an error when running the code.

Comment: But you could be right. I caused an error
`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: But what shell I do if I want to do strong typing checks, but by adding `str` typing it causes `pylance` to go crazy if I assign Field value.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to type a field to get attribute hints (methods and attributes) of the value of the field and don't get linting errors when using strong or basic typing would be to use `Union` and do something like this:

`username: str|CharField = CharField()`